# Problem in response with alexa custom skill using ngrok

Tags: python, python-2.7, alexa-skills-kit, gpio, flask-ask

I'm working on Alexa custom skill by using Alexa voice control to control raspberry gpio pins, I followed each and every steps mentioned here https://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-With-Amazon-Echo-and-Pyt/ but this is giving me response error

I tried degrading cryptography to 2.2.
Re-starting the server.
Re-building the model.

```
logging.getLogger("flask_ask").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
@ask.intent('GPIOControlIntent', mapping={'status': 'status', 'pin': 'pin'})
def gpio_control(status, pin):

    try:
        pinNum = int(pin)
    except Exception as e:
        return statement('Pin number not valid.')

    GPIO.setup(pinNum, GPIO.OUT)

    if status in ['on', 'high']:    GPIO.output(pinNum, GPIO.HIGH)
    if status in ['off', 'low']:    GPIO.output(pinNum, GPIO.LOW)

    return statement('Turning pin {} {}'.format(pin, status))
```

The error I got:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2019 00:04:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 - Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 728, in _flask_view_func
    ask_payload = self._alexa_request(verify=self.ask_verify_requests)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 662, in _alexa_request
    cert = verifier.load_certificate(cert_url)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 21, in load_certificate
    if not _valid_certificate(cert):   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 63, in _valid_certificate
    value = str(extension)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 779, in __str__
    return self._subjectAltNameString()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 740, in _subjectAltNameString
    method = _lib.X509V3_EXT_get(self._extension) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2019 00:04:28] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 - Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 728, in _flask_view_func
    ask_payload = self._alexa_request(verify=self.ask_verify_requests)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/core.py", line 662, in _alexa_request
    cert = verifier.load_certificate(cert_url)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 21, in load_certificate
    if not _valid_certificate(cert):   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_ask/verifier.py", line 63, in _valid_certificate
    value = str(extension)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 779, in __str__
    return self._subjectAltNameString()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 740, in _subjectAltNameString
    method = _lib.X509V3_EXT_get(self._extension) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try degrading it to less than 2.2

```
pip install 'cryptography<2.2'
```

Comment: Did you try cryptography==1.8.1 with pip uninstall pyOpenSSL as well?